# import vue-awesome icons error while jest testing with nuxt on node 13.9.0

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, font-awesome, nuxt.js, babel-jest

I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/Justineo/vue-awesome

in my jest.config.js I add the following

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules(?![\\\\/]vue-awesome[\\\\/])/'
]
```

my nuxt.config.js

```js
build: {
  transpile: [/^vue-awesome/] // enable font-awesome integration.
},
```

The icons work just fine when I'm running the dev box, but I get the following when I run `yarn test`:

```sh
[path/to/project]/node_modules/vue-awesome/icons/building.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Icon from '../components/Icon.vue'
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

explicitly, the issue seems to be something to do with how babel reads (or overlooks) the imports above the Icon component import.  So, for example, given the `building.js` in the error log above, here is how the import looks in the vuejs file:

```
<script>
import 'vue-awesome/icons/building'
import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon'

export default {
  componentes: {
    'v-icon': Icon
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have to explicitly mock the component and its imports at the top of the file (below the imports)

the following works for my test.

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { AxiosSpy, MockNuxt } from 'jest-nuxt-helper'
import index from '@/pages/courses/index'

// MOCKS:
jest.mock('vue-awesome/icons/building', () => '')
jest.mock('vue-awesome/components/Icon', () => '<div></div>')

...
```